# What does "mazik the rabim" mean?

Tags: hebrew, rabbis, sin

The Va’ad HaRabbonim of Greater Cleveland has issued [a statement](https://www.localjewishnews.com/2020/03/17/statement-from-the-vaad-harabbonim-of-greater-cleveland-recovid-19/) about the COVID-19 virus that contains the following paragraph:

> Additionally, anyone who was exposed to someone who tested positive for COVID-19, MUST self-quarantine for 14 days. This is relevant to potential cases in our community (Heaven forbid), or people returning home from other regions, be it the East Coast or Israel. Anyone exposed who does not self-quarantine is *mazik* the *rabim*; a very grave sin.

What does the phrase "*mazik* the *rabim*" mean here? What is its literal translation, and what does it mean in context?

Answer (score 6):

It means "causing damage to the public".

In context, people who come in contact with one another are at risk of giving each other COVID-19 and spreading it further.